# Nuxt3 Js "self-signed cretificate error" when backend is on https

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, self-signed, nuxtjs3

**My backend (API endpoints) is running on https://localhost:44308/api. When that is the case, Nuxt3.js is giving the following error:**

```
request to https://localhost:44308/api/menus failed, reason: self signed certificate ()
at async $fetchRaw2 (/C:/D/MyApp/Source/WebUser/app/node_modules/ohmyfetch/dist/chunks/fetch.mjs:131:20)
at async Proxy.fetchData (/C:/D/MyApp/Source/WebUser/app/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:52133:22)
at async setup (/C:/D/MyApp/Source/WebUser/app/.nuxt/dist/server/server.mjs:68832:5)
```

**My code :**

```
async fetchData() {
      const config = useRuntimeConfig();
      const result = await $fetch(`${config.apiBase}/menus`, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          "Accept-Language": "en",
          // Authorization: `Bearer ${useRuntimeConfig().apiSecret}`,
        },
      });
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }
```

**What is the solution for this? I have seen threads suggesting to run Nuxt3.js.
Someone please help me. Thank you very much**

Answer (score 6):

It's throwing that error because the localhost API is only behind a self signed certificate, for production always use a real authorized certificate.

To work with self signed certs while your just testing it out in development you can do the following.

Create a .env file in your nuxt3 root directory if you haven't got one already. Then add the line:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0
```

Then run

```
npm run dev
```

The dev server will make requests to the API and ignore the fact that it's self signed cert is unauthorized.

For testing the build on a dev machine when the API has a self signed cert, after running

```
npm run build
```

Then start the server with:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED='0' node .output/server/index.mjs
```

The API requests will work in the built version now too, but every request will helpfully throw the following reminder warning:

> Warning: Setting the NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED environment variable
> to '0' makes TLS connections and HTTPS requests insecure by disabling
> certificate verification.

Comment: If you've already created your own CA authority for making your own locally trusted certs, this is a better way to allow for the api using a self signed:

env NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS=./ca.cert.pem node .output/server/index.mjs

Comment: it should be `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` in .env

Comment: it just doesnt work. I'm using vue/nuxt 3 and I've done 3 things:


1.  allowed edge://flags/#allow-insecure-localhost (enabled)
2. created and added cert to trusted authories certicates (windows)
3. package.json scripts: "dev": "set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 && nuxt dev --https --ssl-cert server.crt --ssl-key server.key"

Comment: I have the same issue... The mentioned fix in the answer is working with 3rd party API but it is not working on self Nuxt API like `useFetch('api/users)'`